# vba changing $c$3 to $d$3

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me?

Actually i am looking for vba script in excel:

i want to change cell location from $c$3 to $d$3 in each iteration

i am trying to use chr method but not working. 
Dashboard is my sheet name

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=DashBoard!$c$8"            'changes,in next iteration it should change to $d$8 and so on till j 
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=DashBoard!$c$9:$c$22"    'changes,in next iteration it should change to $d$9:$d$22  and so on till j

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim associatedChar

t = 67

For i = 1 To 2
    For j = 1 To 8
        For k = 1 To 8
            If (Check(i, j, k) = True) Then
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
                ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=DashBoard!$C$8"
                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=DashBoard!$C$9:$C$22"

                associatedChar = Chr(67)
                'this is i am trying to use my associate value is intially $c$8 in next
                'iterattion i want it to change to $d$8 then to $e$8 and so on.`enter code here`

                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=DashBoard!$associatedChar$8"            'changes
                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=DashBoard!$associatedChar$9:$associatedChar$22"    'changes

                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=DashBoard!$B$9:$B$22"
                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=DashBoard!$B$9:$B$22"
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: i am trying    For t = 3 To 10
                    
                           
                    
                            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = " Worksheets(DashBoard).Cells(8,t)"            'changes
                            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "Worksheets(DashBoard).Cells(9,t):Worksheets(DashBoard).Cells(9,3)"    'changes
                           
                  
                         
                    
                            Next t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does replacing `associatedChar` with `" & associatedChar& "` within the code help at all?

Comment: No probs mate. Whenever you insert a string into an expression like this thats what you do :)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use .Cells references instead of .Range.    Cells(row, col) can use numbers instead of a string reference like Range.

For example:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
For row = 2 to LastRow

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 2) = whatever.

Next row
```

Comment: For t = 3 To 10
                    
                           
                    
                            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = " Worksheets(DashBoard).Cells(8,t)"            'changes
                            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "Worksheets(DashBoard).Cells(9,t):Worksheets(DashBoard).Cells(9,3)"    'changes
                           
                  
                         
                    
                            Next t